# If $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}} = 0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_{n}$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a_{n} \geq 0$ and $b_{n}>0$ for each $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$ and suppose that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}} = 0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_{n}$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges.

The hint in the books says that proof should be similar to the Limit Comparison Test for Integrals.

Note that there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}} < 1$ or $a_{n} < b_{n}$ for all $n > N$.  Then, we have $0 \leq a_{n} < b_{n}$ for $n > N$ and by the Comparison Test, $\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges.  Then since, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_{n} + \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ and both $\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_{n}$ and $\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converge, it must be the case that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges.

Does this look right to anyone.

Comment: You were done already after "and by the Comparison Test..." . No need to add the rest if you know a finite ammount of summands makes no diffeence about the convergence/divergence of a series.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=0\implies a_n\le b_n\;,\;\;\text{for all}\;\;n>N\;,\;\;\text{for some}\;\;N\in\Bbb N$$

and now apply the usual comparison test.